# MySQL, best way to insert 1000 rows

Tags: mysql, insert

I have an "item" table with the following structure:
    item
      id
      name
      etc.

Users can put items from this item table into their inventory.  I store it in the inventory table like this:

```
inventory
  id
  item_id
  user_id
```

Is it OK to insert 1000 rows into inventory table?  What is the best way to insert 1000 rows?

Comment: Inserting 1000 records should not be a problem for any DBMS worth it's salt but can't you just add the `collection(id)` to the user's `inventory` instead of adding each item?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question to make it more readable. Don't forget to use preview panel below the text box where you type!

Comment: @Lieven, the items in the collection could change after the user takes it.  So it depends on whether you want the user's set of items to stay the set they took, or update automatically as the collection changes.

Comment: @Bill Karwin - It might be safe to assume collections could change but at present we don't know that. If they don't, it's far easier to just point to the right collection. In the end, it depends on what the use case is. Even *if* collections change, I can imagine users *wanting* to have these changes.

Comment: @Lieven, I agree, it's not clear from the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL can handle millions of records in a single table without any tweaks. With little tweaks it can handle hundreds of millions (I did that). So I wouldn't worry about that.

To improve insert performance you should use batch inserts.

```
insert into table my_table(col1, col2) VALUES (val1_1, val2_1), (val1_2, val2_2);
```

Storing records to a file and using `load data infile` yields even better results (best in my case), but it requires more effort.

Answer (score 1):

It's okay to insert 1000 rows. You should do this as a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html) so the indices are updated all at once at the commit.

You can also construct a single INSERT statement to insert many rows at a time. (See the syntax for [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).) However, I wonder how advisable it would be to do that for 1,000 rows.

Most efficient would probably be to use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) or [LOAD XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html)

Answer (score 1):

When it gets to 1000's, I usually use write to a pipe-delimited CSV file and use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) to suck it in quick.  By writing to disk, you avoid issues with overflowing your string buffer, if the language you are using has limits on string size.  LOAD DATA INFILE is optimized for bulk uploads.

I've done this with up to **1 billion rows** (on a cheap $400 4GB 3 year old 32-bit Ubuntu box), so one thousand is not an issue.

Added note:  if you don't care about the `id` assigned and you just want a new unique ID for every record you insert, you could consider setting up [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) on `id` in the table and let Mysql assign an ID for you.

Comment: I imagine that one can put billions of rows into a single table. But what read/write performance will MySQL have in this case? But, I guess, this is out of scope here.

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev fwiw, it took me 20min to load 1bln but you have to configure Mysql correctly when you use up all your memory - ref: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/44688/ - you are essentially constrained by memory and by indexes.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of also depends on how many users you have, if you have 1,000,000 users all doing 1,000 inserts every few minutes then the server is going to struggle to keep up. From a mysql point of view it is certainly capable of handling that much data.